# Generate JQPlot charts in Server

Tags: jsf, jqplot, rhino

We are using JQplot for generating charts and so far everything has worked like a charm. However we are facing a blocking issue.

As per the user requirements, we need to display all charts in form of a PDF. I am able to create a pdf for each chart individually, by creating a Base64 file using the "jqplotToImageElem" method and sending it to the server where I create the PDF using iText. However there can be hundred's of charts in a report. On the front end we are showing them one at a time but in the back-end we have to print all of them. Now sending the Image data for these many is practically impossible.

I am also exploring using Rhino+EnvJS to call the JQPlot in the bean which is working(creating the chart object) but when I try to get the image file using "jqplotToImageElem", I get a NoSuchMethod exception because EnvJs doesn't support the toDataURL() method for the HTMLCanvas object.

It is a dead end. Is there a way out or I should approach the issue in any other way .

We are using: JSF 2.0 + Jquery + iText.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: This is the same problem posted: 



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243332/jqplot-to-image

Comment: The problem as mentioned is not for the creation of one chart. I know how to convert that to PNG and then send it to the server and create the PDF etc. However if you have a considerable number of charts that need to be converted, this approach will not work since you can not send all that image data to the server for conversion.