# Axis label hidden while saving a jqPlot graph to an image file

Tags: jquery, jqplot

**Edit**: I am using jqplotToImageStr({}) to save the chart image. However the resulting image does not include the axis labels. It only outputs the chart itself. I found out that the axis labels are actually behind the chart. I had moved the axis labels inside the chart boundary and set z-index so that the labels are shown on top of the chart. But when jqplotToImageStr({}) is called the axis labels fall behind the chart. How do I make sure that the axis labels are included in the image at time of capture?

here is the code to create the image.

```
var imageData = $('#chart_div').jqplotToImageStr({});
var copyImage = $('<img/>').attr('src', imageData);
$('#copy-container').html(copyImage);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bipindas.

Comment: @Bipindas: Would you mind sharing your approach? I think I got a similar issue. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642063/set-resolution-and-image-size-in-jqplottoimagestr/19643739?noredirect=1#19643739

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to sort this out. I used a canvas and drew the axis labels on the canvas after drawing the chart. Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243332/jqplot-to-image).

```
function jqplotToImg(obj) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    newCanvas.width = obj.find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").width();
    newCanvas.height = obj.find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").height();
    var baseOffset = obj.find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").offset();

    // make white background for pasting
    var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

    obj.children().each(function () {

        if ($(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'canvas') {
            // all canvas from the chart
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,
                        offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                        offset.top - baseOffset.top
                    );
        } // for the div's with the X and Y axis
    });

    obj.children().each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div') {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == "jqplot-axis jqplot-yaxis") {

                $(this).children("canvas").each(function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,
                                offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                                offset.top - baseOffset.top
                            );
                });
            }
            else if ($(this).attr('class') == "jqplot-axis jqplot-xaxis") {

                $(this).children("canvas").each(function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,
                                offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                                offset.top - baseOffset.top
                            );
                });
            }
        }
    });
```